# how to fetch single data from row and store in variable insqlite using python

Tags: sqlite

this is my programme in python I have to fetch single data and want store in variable that I can compare with my live data

```
import sqlite3 as lite

con = lite.connect("test.db")

cur=con.cursor()
cur.execute("select  * from CardData where CardId =?",[num])
result1 = cur.fetchone()

 row1 = result1[0]
 row2 = result1[1]

if not  row1 == num and row2 == "40":
 do this
```

Comment: my Table is CardData(SrNumber,CardID,Timein,Timeout,ExpiryDate,Access)

Comment: And the problem is?..